# How to integrate Cocos2d-javascript engine with Eclipse?

Tags: javascript, eclipse

I'm newbie with a JS development so forgive me for this question. I didn't find any information regarding this topic.

Cocos2d-javascript creates a specific structure and has some scripts for compiling a project. So the only option I see is to use notepad++ or another editor. Is it possible to integrate it into Eclipse?